# On convergence theorems for limit calculations.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I came across the following limit $$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{lim}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{e^x}}{1+nx^2}dx$$
and I can't use any convergence theorem to show that this is equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty}0dx=0$. I can't use Monotonous convergence theorem because the functions of the sequence are not positive. I also can't use the Bounded convergence theorem because $m((0,\infty))$ is not finite. I also tried Dominated convergence theorem, but I can't find a good function $g\in L^{1}$ that dominates all $f_{n}$. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just
$$\left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin e^x}{1+n x^2}\,dx\right|\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+nx^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
?

Comment: Well, yeah! Why not? Thank you, I couldn't think of such idea.